# installing JDK and it shows empty icon

Tags: java, android-studio, sdk

When I tried to install the JDK, it was installed but in start->java Development Kit: I faced with "empty"word.

But when I went to cmd and writed `javac version` or `java version` I saw true results and when I tried to install SDK for programming android with eclipse or install android studio I had not any problem for installing

But after installing when I created a new project in both softwares I had problems.

What I must do? Every time I try to install JDK it is installed as now.

[image]

Comment: _when i created a new project in both softwares i had problems_... What problems

Comment: in eclipse R.java file in gen folder couldn't created. and all of my tries had no result so i had to install android studio and about it i had this error:       public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {...}

Comment: in eclipse, R.java file in gen folder couldn't created. and all of my tries had no result so i had to install android studio and about it ; this error exists: it deprecate android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Comment: Deprecation is not an error. You must be getting a warning to not use deprecated classes. This is normal, and ideally you should try to avoid deprecated classes, as they will no longer be supported. But your code will work nonetheless.